# Why does my API POST Request keep failing?

Tags: c#, json, api, post, httprequest

I am doing an API Post request and cant seem to get it to work. I always get a sendFailure webexception and the response for the exception is always null so catching the exception is useless. It keeps happening when I try to get the httpWebResponse. I noticed too the request.contentlength gave errors at postream getrequeststream so i commented it out. Test.json is the file I use for the request body. I also tested this on different API testers by including the URL, body, and content-type in the header and they worked. I just cant seem to code it for myself. The credentials work I just dont know if im doing the request correctly?

JSON File:

```
{
"email": "abc@123.com", 
"password": "12345", 
"facilityNumber": "987654"
}

string filepath = "test.json";

string result = string.Empty;

using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filepath))
{

   var json = r.ReadToEnd();

   var jobj = JObject.Parse(json);

   foreach (var item in jobj.Properties())
   {

      item.Value = item.Value.ToString().Replace("v1", "v2");
   }

   result = jobj.ToString();

   Console.WriteLine(result);
}

try
{

   string setupParameters;

   HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.test.com/abcde");

   request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;

   setupParameters = result;

   ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, cert, chain, ssl) => true;

   ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();

   var postData = setupParameters;

   request.Method = "POST";

   request.ContentType = "application/json";

   byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

   //request.ContentLength = data.Length;

   using (StreamWriter postStream = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))//error if uncomment contentlength
   {

      postStream.Write(postData);

      postStream.Flush();

      postStream.Close();
   }

   HttpWebResponse wr = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();//error occurs

   Stream receiveStream = wr.GetResponseStream();

   StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8);
}
catch (WebException ex)
{

   if (ex.Response != null)
   {

      using (var errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)ex.Response)
      {

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(errorResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {

           string error = reader.ReadToEnd();

           result = error;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you use something like Fiddler to track the http traffic on your machine, what do you see when that request is attempted?

Comment: And also check the headers, etc, on the working requests also, to see the difference between the two.

Comment: request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post and request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf8" to see if that solves your issue

Answer (score 0):

I suggest modifiying your request to follow this format. Especially pay attention to the request.Method and request.ContentType which have caught me out multiple times.
Also, handling the response is easier this way.

```
try
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(YOURURL);
                request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf8";
                request.Headers.Add(ADD HEADER HERE IF YOU NEED ONE);
                request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post; // IMPORTANT

                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                     streamWriter.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(JSONBODYSTRING)); 
// I USUALLY YOU JSONCONVERT HERE TO SIMPLY SERIALIZE A STRING CONTAINING THE JSON INFO. 
//BUT I GUESS YOUR METHOD WOULD ALSO WORK
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }

                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    string result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    // DO WHATEVER YOU'D LIKE HERE
                }
            } catch (Exception ex)
            {
               // HANDLE YOUR EXCEPTIONS
            }
```

Comment: Unfortunately Im still getting the same error: Underlying connection was closed, unexpected error occurred on send

Comment: @Cavaliers2016 can you try the above code without reading from your json file and simply saving the following string and passing that as the streamWriter.Write parameter: var json = "{
\"email\": \"abc@123.com\", 
\"password\": \"12345\", 
\"facilityNumber\": \"987654\"
}"